# openxlsx number of worksheets

Tags: r, export-to-excel, xlsx, openxlsx

I'm learning openxlsx in R.  I have no problem creating a workbook, adding a worksheet or saving a workbook until I try to save the 4th worksheet I created.  Does anyone know if there is a limit on the number of worksheets that can be saved to a workbook created in R using openxlsx?  When I try to save the workbook after writing data for the 4th sheet I get this error message:
Error in comment_list[[i]] : subscript out of bounds.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using XLConnect.

Comment: Package `xlsx` is another option

Comment: This has been fixed on [github #116](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/116).

Comment: I can confirm - there is no problem. I can add `n` number of worksheets to any `.xlsx` file I have read in.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit in number of worksheets to any `.xlsx`

Example:

```
library(openxlsx)
iris
wb <- createWorkbook()
for (i in 1:8) {
  addWorksheet(wb,i)
  writeDataTable(wb,i,iris)
}
saveWorkbook(wb, 'Exports/prueba.xlsx', overwrite = T)
```

Comment: Thanks - there was when I originally posted the question in 2015 and it was fixed in 2015.